# Differences among various bool types?

Tags: java, android, boolean

What are the differences among bool, boolean and Boolean in Java/Android?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`bool` does not seem to exist, at least I can't find references to it.

`boolean` is a primitive boolean type, *not* an object.

`Boolean` is the wrapper object for a `boolean`.

Comment: bool doesn't exist.

Answer (score 34):

`boolean` is a java primitive type. It only accepts `true` or `false` (which are declared constants in java).

**Boolean** is a Serializable wrapper of `boolean` primitive type. From the JDK....

> The `Boolean` class wraps a value of
>   the primitive type boolean in an
>   object. An object of type Boolean
>   contains a single field whose type is
>   `boolean`.

`bool` doesn't exist in java, but it does in Android as [`R.bool`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.bool.html).

Comment: So what is Android's R.bool for?

Comment: I've heard of `android.R` but I have no clue what it's uses are...maybe it's for the R programming language.

Comment: Ah! `R.bool` is a "resource type" in Android.  God only knows why Google decided to ignore Java identifier conventions with the name.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `R` programming language.

Answer (score 0):

boolean is a primitive boolean type and occupies less memory.
Boolean is the wrapper object for a boolean which introduced in JDK 1.5.

1. Suppose you have a service API which will execute a query and get the data from multiple tables.
2. After that this data is to be manipulated and converted into the json object.
3. During this conversion, it ight be possible that some boolean field may have 'NULL' as value.
4. While receiving it as a response, you will definately parse it into an object.
5. This automatic conversion may fail if your conversion logic will try to parse Boolean 'NULL' value into boolean primitive variable because boolean can't accept 'NULL' values.